Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion Proof
I have been doing the book "Olympiad Mathematics" and this is the proof provided for Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion.
Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion Proof
In the last two lines of the proof, it is written that,

We have $p\mid a_i$ and by supposition $p$ divides each one of $b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_{i-1}$, so $p \mid b_ic_0$. But $p\nmid c_0 \Rightarrow p \mid b_i$, which is a contradiction.
Therefore $f(x)$ is irreducible.

But since $p \nmid a_n$, shouldn't the proof be like this,

$p$ divides each one of $b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_{i-1}$ and since $p\nmid b_i, c_0$, this implies $p \nmid a_i$, so $a_i$ can only be $a_n$, the only coefficient of $f(x)$ which is not divisible by $p$, which means $i = n$.


Since the polynomial factors of $f(x)$ should have degrees less than $n$, $i = n$ implies that we have not achieved a factorisation. Hence f(x) is irreducible.

I cannot understand what is being "contradicted" in the book's proof, and how that "contradiction" implies that $f(x)$ is irreducible. And also why the book says that $p \mid a_i$ when $p \nmid a_n$.
Any help on the topic would be appreciated!

Hi, it’s great that you started using MathJax! I’ve edited it so that it looks as it’s supposed to.

Thanks @Aphelli! I have been using Mathematics Stack Exchange for looking explanations for a long time but I never realised that it took so much effort to write using MathJax :)

Don’t worry, you’ll get used to it, it gets faster (at least on an actual keyboard – on a phone I’m afraid it remains a bit of a pain)! :)

First of all, the book says that $p\mid a_{i}$ when $0 \leq i \leq n-1$ because this is the first hypothesis of Eisenstein's Irreducibility Criterion.
Second, you have that $m<n$ because if $m=n$ you will have that $k=0$, and you are assuming that $f(x)$ is not irreducible in the proof, so $0<m,k<n$ and $m+k=n$ (because a degree zero polynomial is constant, and by definition, a polynomial is not irreducible when it can be decomposed in the product of two non constant polynomials).
In consequence, $a_{i} \neq a_{n}$ because the index $i \in\{0,...,m\}$, that is less than $n$.
The contradiction yields in the fact that you will obtain $p\mid b_{i}$ using Euclid's lemma and the fact that $p\mid a_{i}$. But you suppose that $p \nmid b_{i}$ and you have a contradiction.
